# How to package library jars except module jar in gradle?

Tags: gradle

How to ask gradle to package just the dependency jars in a zip *without* the module jar that contains the module classes?

I'm using Kotlin Gradle DSL, but Groovy solutions also welcomed. I can translate them to Kotlin myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up [a `Zip` task](https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/bundling/Zip.html) as follows:

```groovy
tasks.register('packageDeps', Zip) {
    from configurations.runtimeClasspath
}
```

It depends on the kind of project you have, which configuration you need to copy from. In the example, it’s a Java project and we copy the dependencies from the runtime classpath (i.e., [the `runtimeClasspath` configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management)). You can run `./gradlew dependencies` to find out which configurations exist in your project; you can only use the ones that are meant to be resolved, i.e., the ones that *don’t* have an `(n)` in their description.

### Example Project

Here’s a self-contained project that I’ve tested this with (not showing Gradle 7.2 Wrapper files):

```
├── build.gradle
├── settings.gradle
└── src
    └── main
        └── java
            └── com
                └── example
                    └── MyClass.java
```

When running `./gradlew packageDeps` on that project, the ZIP file `build/distributions/my-deps.zip` is created which contains only dependency JARs (incl. transitive ones) and *not* the `MyClass.class` file or a corresponding JAR.

#### `build.gradle`

```groovy
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.2-jre'
}

tasks.register('packageDeps', Zip) {
    from configurations.runtimeClasspath
    archiveFileName = 'my-deps.zip'
}
```

#### `settings.gradle`

(empty)

#### `src/main/java/com/example/MyClass.java`

```java
package com.example;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}
```